# How can I use values in an old dataframe to calculate a new dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe with certain values and I want to create a new dataframe with percentage differences from the old dataframe.

My existing dataframe is something like this:

```
Years          A              B          C           D          E
2020        801.566522  769.2986786 830.8725406 830.8725406 840.7192069
2021-2030   786.3122361 759.3832642 826.2453567 826.2453567 838.7446964
2031-2050   787.6490105 759.1486884 827.4489946 827.4489946 839.8352851
2041-2050   775.1016567 745.1193567 817.2389842 817.2389842 831.9880991
```

The new dataframe should calculate the percentage difference between the 2020 values and the values between subsequent decades, and should look something like this.

```
Years           A                 B               C                D            E
2021-2030   -0.019030593    -0.012888901    -0.005569066    -0.005569066    -0.002348597
2031-2050   -0.01736289     -0.013193823    -0.004120423    -0.004120423    -0.001051388
2041-2050   -0.03301643     -0.031430344    -0.016408722    -0.016408722    -0.010385284
```

I can do this in excel quite easily but since I have a large number of these files, I wanted to do it in python instead. Can anyone help me out with a basic solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Just do

`df=yourdataframe.pct_change()`

The first row of the dataframe will be of NaN values and if you'd like to keep it in the format you'd shown just

`yourdataframe=df.iloc[1:]`

This will remove the first row of the dataframe

Comment: I only got back to this work a few days ago, and while this solution is nice and concise, it calculates difference between current and previous rows, while i was looking for percentage difference from the first row. Just putting this in here in case anyone else is using this solution